# Is it possible to change axis2 soap address without compiling the project all over again?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I generate service code using the command

wsdl2java -uri AuthenticationService.wsdl [params]

then make changes to a few generated files and deploy my war file. But the issue is i have deployed this file to QA environment and it has a soap address (epr - end point reference) which is pointing to QA box.

```
<!-- Soap Service Endpoint -->
<service name="SforceAuthenticationService">
    <documentation>Sforce Authentication Service</documentation>
    <port binding="tns:AuthenticationBinding" name="AuthenticationService">
        <soap:address location="https:[QA URL]/myapp/services/MyService"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

To push to production it seems that in my wsdl file and i need to change the url and run the wsdl2java command again which will create new files, and then again i have to make changes in couple of java classes. Ideally i would like to push to production when QA signs off without having to build again! Is it possbile to do this by changing the soap address via admin console? I couldn't find anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its possible with wsdl2java. I couldn't quickly find anything to answer that. However it is possible to avoid this problem using other technologies. I'm not so familiar with using wsdls to generate as most of the time I have had to work from java. I have used spring-ws and jax-ws to generate ws from java. When going this way, the generated service run on a url at the server its deployed at, so there is no ever having to worry about the address. Maybe you should have a look at spring-ws and jax-ws, they probably hold the answer for you. Someone else maybe able to expand on what I've said.